# Meaning of "crawling up the walls"

Tags: meaning

What's the meaning of *crawling up the walls*?

> I work at home and I could easily stay here for a month or two... I rarely get to stay in for so long cause I always have stuff to do in the weekends, bills to pay or stuff with the wife but I love staying at home.
>
> F*** that, I couldn't do a week without getting out. 3-4 days and I'm **crawling up the walls**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not a literal phrase. The speaker is saying that they will have an excess of energy that they must find an outlet for and, failing that, they will, figuratively, "crawl up the wall" to release that energy.

It's similar to the term "cabin fever" which is in reference to the tendency of a person to begin feeling temporarily claustrophobic after they have been inside the same building for an extended amount of time, such as during a blizzard or flood.

Answer (score 0):

I figure of speech based on a person who can't stand being sat inside all day when he/she likes to be out and about and active. 
e.g if a postman was given a job sat in a call centre for 8 hours drinking coffee all day in summer. They wouldn't be able to deal with it. After a few hours they would be 'crawling up the walls.'